# Possible to create a PowerShell script that can open a query, update the date to the last business date, and then execute?

Tags: sql, powershell, automation

I'm new to Power Shell, and I'm exploring the possibility of automating some of my daily tasks. Some of these tasks include opening queries, updating the date inside the query, and then executing. It would save so much time if I could write a PowerShell script that did all this for me.

I already have a script that can open a specified file, but I'm struggling trying to figure out how to add on to this capability. I've done multiple Google and Stack Overflow searches, but I've been unsuccessful in finding someone with the same issue.

Comment: You forgot to post your script. You also forgot to tell us what you're querying and how/where the query strings are stored :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This case does not contain enough detail to be able to help. Please take the Tour and provide a [mcve].